No Code coverage for excuted code
Our unit test shows the code is being executed as shown below at line 65 but 0% code coverage detected:

However, deployment failed reporting 0% code coverage for Exceptions class:


Does this answer your question? How do I increase my code coverage, or why can't I cover these lines?

Code coverage collection with parallel test execution has historically had some problems whereby the coverage values from one test execution can overwrite those of another. That said, it seems you are indicating that the exception class itself isn't being covered. You could easily add an explicit unit test that simply constructs your exception and asserts that the exception instance returned is not null...

@DavidCheng Not relevant here. The code coverage is as it should be.

@PhilW The class cannot be covered, because classes don't count as executable statements.

I'm looking at the constructor for the exception. Yes, it is empty, but can it not be counted?

I was confused by the post, I thought the OP wanted to cover lines 58-62.

@PhilW There's no constructor. This class inherits its constructors from its parent, Exception. There's no lines of code to cover.

Oh yeah. D'oh... should have read that more closely. Didn't track that it is a nested class...

This is by design. Class and interface declarations don't count as executable code. Neither do System.debug calls, commented lines, test methods, and interface or abstract method declarations. You can deploy classes that have zero executable statements, despite the UI showing zero coverage.

You need to identify which Test Class or combination of Test Classes cover more than 75% of your targeted Apex Class. Try using this Chrome Extension to help identify the Test Class and its aggregated code coverage.
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/salesforce-explorer/fadogcggoffogihhniomllnflihoihnf
